# javascript iframe resize at every load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, resize

I want to resize an iframe every time a new link is accessed inside that iframe.

I have a wordpress blog and I added the forum on a page using this iframe. I want it resized every time I click on a link on that blog.

I googled but I found nothing relevant.

This is the code I am using for my resize

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sizeIFrame() {
var helpFrame = jQuery("#ifm");
var innerDoc = (helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ? helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument :     helpFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
helpFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 35);
}
</script>
<iframe id="ifm" src="..." width="100%" frameBorder="0" onload="sizeIFrame();" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to invoke the jquery `height` method on the document object itself without a jquery wrapping... is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but it could be that the iframe was only loaded one time?... extrange...

I don't know, but I think that you could add one onclick function to every link of the blog to launch the sizeIframe function instead of the onload.

For example (this code is an idea, not tested)...

```
<a href="#" class="iframe-mgr" id ="link-a"> a link </a>
<a href="#" class="iframe-mgr" id ="link-b"> b link </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.iframe-mgr').addEventListener('click', function(){ sizeIframe () } );
</script>
```

Comment: The forum is phpbb and I could modify it but it's complicated.

Comment: I found a Wordpress plugin called iFrame Wrapper that makes a perfect resize but another problem camed up.

After the iframe is resized, it will remain at that size until the page is refreshed. Let's say 1'st page needs 500px to be displayed. The second one needs 1000px. This plugin resize the iframe to 1000px height but if I click again on the first page, it will be still 1000px.

Comment: Uhm... and could you set the height of this iframe class to (window.innerHeight - mainContentHeight) being mainContentHeight the height of the other visible layers? ...
o even the offset height: iframe_height = window.innerHeight - $(#iframe_layer).offsetHeight...
?
Hope it will be usefull for you